# Почему не работает replaceWith?

Tags: javascript

Есть код на JavaScript:

```
if (i === 0){
 Document.getElementById("percent_bar").insertAdjacentHTML("<p id=\"rate\">" + heartRate[0] + " - " + heartRate[1] + "</p>");
i++;
}
else{
$("p.rate").replaceWith("<p id=\"rate\">" + heartRate[0] + " - " + heartRate[1] + "</p>");
```

Текст должен меняться в соответствие с новым значением `heartRate`.
`Percent_bar` - элемент div.
`i` - глобальная переменная, весь код - фрагмент `onClick`.

**Обновление**

```
Переписал вот так:

if (i === 0){
    document.getElementById("blue-view").insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', "<p class=\"blue\">" + lowHeartRateValue[0] +" - "+ lowHeartRateValue[1] + "</p>");
} else {
    $("p.blue").replaceWith("<p class=\"blue\">" + lowHeartRateValue[0] + " - " + lowHeartRateValue[1] + "</p>");
i++;
```

Также в файле со стилями создал соответствующий, но пустой, стиль.
Всё равно не работает. Значения пересчитываются, но не меняются.

Не судите строго, я в JS всего 1 день.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

У вас у тэга `<p>`выставлен не `class`, а `id`. Поэтому и искать его нужно не по селектору класса, а по селектору идентификатора:

```
$("p#rate").replaceWith(...
```

или просто

```
$("#rate").replaceWith(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, объект `document` пишется с маленькой буквы, во вторых, непонятно зачем вы сравниваете `i` как ссылку, если это переменная, хватило бы просто

```
if(i == 0)
```

`.insertAdjacentHTML` - прочитайте документацию на данную функцию, целесообразно ли вообще её использование.

Второе, имеются ли вообще у вас элемент с

```
<p class="rate"></p>
```

В противном случае что оно заменять будет? Данная функция находит элемент и его заменяет на то что вы указываете, если такого элемента нету то и заменять нечего.

Comment: Про сравнение - написана глупость. Оператор `===` - это не "сравнение как ссылки", а "строгое сравнение".